# Java Generics - Specifying upper bound on a class implementing an interface which itself specifies an upper bound

Tags: java, generics, extends, implements

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ISort<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public void sort(T[] array);
}
```

My understanding of this is that the the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` tells the compiler that within this class, there may be some generic types `T`, and they must be a `Comparable<T>` or be any class which implements `Comparable<T>`.

I then have the following class:

```
public class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ISort<T> {

    public void swap(T[] array, int i, int j) {
        T temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    public void sort(T[] array) {
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
    }

}
```

Again, I have the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` telling the compiler that within this class I will be using the type `T` which must form an IS-A relationship with `Comparable<T>`. However, why must I only type `implements ISort<T>`, why do I not need to write `implements ISort<T extends Comparable<T>>`? In order to help me understand this could you explain what exactly these generics statements are inferring to the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between specifying `T` with the class and using `T` in the extends or implements clause.

When specifying `T` with the class, you are *declaring* the type parameter `T`, but in the extends or implements clause, you are *using* a type parameter that is already declared.

```
public class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>>  // Declare T to be Comparable<T>
    implements ISort<T>                     // Use T
```

Using a type parameter in the extends or implements clause is no different than using the type parameter in the body of the class.

Comment: This explanation makes the most sense to me. However, I still have a few questions. If I am simply using `T` in the `implements ...` part, that means we have already ensured that `T`'s upper bound is `Comparable<T>`. If that's the case, then why do I need to specify `T extends Comparable<T>` in the interface file (my first code snippet)?

Comment: Each class/interface can define its own type parameters.  `ISort` is declaring its own `T` to be `Comparable<T>`, and `Sort` is declaring its own `T` to be `Comparable<T>` also.  The implements clause on `Sort` indicates that `Sort` is supplying its own `T` as `ISort`'s type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for generic type usage is `SomeType<SomeTypeArgument>`.

In your case

```
class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ISort<T> {
        // ^ declares new type parameter             ^ uses it as a type argument 
        //
```

You declare a new type parameter `T` with bounds that match the expectations in the type parameter `T` declared in `ISort`. You can therefore use `Sort#T` as a type argument for `ISort`.

This would be similar to

```
class Sort implements ISort<Integer> {
```

The only difference is you don't declare a type parameter, you use an existing type.

Answer (score 0):

In the class declaration you introduce a type parameter with an upper bound. When you use `T[]` as the type of the first parameter of the `sort` method, you are not **declaring** anything (the declaration happens at the beginning of the file): you are merely **using** a type variable. Please, note the different phrasing:

- at the beginning of the file, you *declare a type parameter*
- in the signature of sort, we *use a type variable*

Bounds on type parameters are only allowed at declaration site, and the declaration can happen in three places:

1. class declaration
2. constructor definition
3. method definition

Here you a quick table:

```
// class
public static class Foo<T> {
    // constructor
    public <A> Foo() {}
    // method
    public <B> void doSomething() {}
    // Not really allowed
    // public void doSomethingElse(List<T extends Number> bar) {}
    // here we have a wildcard, so you can do this
    public void doSomethingElse(List<? super T> bar) {}
}
```